# I have 2 types of links <a> but only one of them work when :HOVER. Why?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a problem with the `:hover links`. The main link(`id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-link"`) works fine for me. But the side links (`class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link"`) don't work at all even if they are done the same way. I want to underline all text in all elements inside the link. How can I fix the problem?

My code:

```css
#big-box-content-topmain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew {
  height: 100%;
  width: 520px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px lightgray solid;
  float: left;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-link {
  color: #102447;
  text-decoration: none
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-link:visited {
  color: #102447;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-imgbox {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: lightgray 1px solid;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-imgbox-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background: rgb(239, 243, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(239, 243, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: lightgray;
  float: left;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-icon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-autorname {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-timepart {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: lightgray;
  float: left;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-timepart-time {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 29px;
  max-height: 58px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox-header {}

.big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox-header {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 122px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox-text {}

.big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox-text {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-otherlist {
  height: 100%;
  width: 440px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link {
  color: #102447;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link:visited {
  color: #102447;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox {
  height: 100%;
  width: 133px;
  float: left;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 133px);
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text {
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="big-box-content-topmain">
    <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew">
      <a id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-link" href="">
        <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-imgbox"><img id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-imgbox-img" src=""></div>
        <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox">
          <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart">
            <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-icon"><img src="" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
            <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-autorname"><span id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-autorname-text">Example.com</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-timepart">
            <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-timepart-time">13:30</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox">
          <h2 id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox-header" class="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox-header">This is header of the main link</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox">
        <p id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox-text" class="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox-text">
          And, this is description of the main link.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist">
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I looked for an answer but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Your code is so....... difficult to read..... you have multiple elements inside your link and you set a `text-underline` to a link not to the `h4`... try `.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link:hover h4 {  text-decoration: underline; }`

Comment: You've mentioned you have a "problem" with something that "doesn't work", but haven't mentioned what the problem is, or in what way something isn't working. Would you edit the question to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. IF I understand what you are trying to ask it's this:

You would like the text inside the div `.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link` to have an underline when a user `:hover`s.

This can be accomplished with the following: `.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link:hover h4{text-decoration: underline}` targeting the H4 in question directly.

you could also do: : `.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link h4:hover{text-decoration: underline}` targeting the H4 only when a user specifically hovers over that element.

Below is your code with the change.

As a side-note consider more general and shorter class names for readability.

```css
#big-box-content-topmain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew {
  height: 100%;
  width: 520px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-right: 1px lightgray solid;
  float: left;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-link {
  color: #102447;
  text-decoration: none
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-link:visited {
  color: #102447;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-imgbox {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: lightgray 1px solid;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-imgbox-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background: rgb(239, 243, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(239, 243, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: lightgray;
  float: left;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-icon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-autorname {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-timepart {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: lightgray;
  float: left;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-timepart-time {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 29px;
  max-height: 58px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox-header {}

.big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox-header {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 122px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox-text {}

.big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox-text {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#big-box-content-topmain-otherlist {
  height: 100%;
  width: 440px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link {
  color: #102447;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link:visited {
  color: #102447;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link:hover h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox {
  height: 100%;
  width: 133px;
  float: left;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 133px);
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text {
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="big-box-content-topmain">
    <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew">
      <a id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-link" href="">
        <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-imgbox"><img id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-imgbox-img" src=""></div>
        <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox">
          <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart">
            <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-icon"><img src="" height="100%" width="100%"></div>
            <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-autorname"><span id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-autorpart-autorname-text">Example.com</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-timepart">
            <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-infoimgbox-timepart-time">13:30</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox">
          <h2 id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox-header" class="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-headerbox-header">This is header of the main link</h2>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox">
        <p id="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox-text" class="big-box-content-topmain-mainew-textbox-text">
          And, this is description of the main link.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist">
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-link">
        <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava">
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox"><img src="" class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-imgbox-img"></div>
          <div class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox">
            <h4 class="big-box-content-topmain-otherlist-zprava-textbox-text">This is text of the link.</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```